# Find area of region bounded by $xy=4, xy=8, xy^3=5, xy^3=15$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find area of region bounded by $xy=4, xy=8, xy^3=5, xy^3=15$.

Can someone help me check if there's anything wrong with my working or conceptual understanding of it? The answer in my textbook is $2\ln3$ but my answer is $\frac{8}{3}\ln3$.

Let $xy=u$ and $xy^3=v$

Calculating change of integrals:

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{y}$
$\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{x}$
$\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}=\frac{1}{y^3}$
$\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}=\frac{1}{3y^2x}$

So, $dydx= (\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}) dudv$

$dydx= \frac{1}{3y^3x}-\frac{1}{y^3x}dudv$

$dydx= -\frac{2}{3y^3x}dudv$

$dydx= -\frac{2}{3v}dudv$

$\int^{15}_5 \int^8 _4  -\frac{2}{3v} dudv  = -\frac{8}{3}\ln3$

Area = $\frac{8}{3}\ln3$

Comment: I think you have the integration limits reversed.  5 and 15 should go with $dv$, not $du.$

Comment: For your notation, are you using $\dfrac{dx}{du}$ to mean $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}$?

Comment: @B.Goddard Edited, thanks! It was a typo on my part. I used the correct integral when evaluating the answer, so I still can't get 2ln3

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Yes, all dx's refer to $\partial x$ here

Comment: @YukiJ Those are curves that I have to find the area bounded by

Answer (score 2):

When you are taking derivative with respect to $u$ (or $v$) you should apply it to both $x$ and $y$, as they are dependent on it. To avoid this problem, express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u,v$ (in particular $x^2= \frac{u^3}{v}$ and $y^2 = \frac vu$)  or an even better solution is to calculate the Jacobian of the inverse trasformation and take the reciprocal value. We have:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = y; \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = x; \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = y^3; \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 3xy^2$$ Then:

$$\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\end{array}\right| = \left|\begin{array}{cc}
y & y^3 \\
x & 3xy^2 \\
\end{array}\right| = 3xy^3-xy^3 = 2xy^3 = 2v$$

Thus your Jacobian is $\frac{1}{2v}$. Now to find the area:

$$\int_5^{15}\int_4^8 \frac{1}{2v} dudv = 2\int_{5}^{15} \frac 1v dv = 2 \ln v \; \bigg|_5^{15} = 2 \ln\left( \frac{15}{5}\right) = 2 \ln 3$$

Comment: Thanks! It really helped! Also I think you made a slight mistake as all your Jacobian inputs are $\partial u$, but it doesn't really matter :)

Comment: @YipJungHon Oh yeah. Fixed it. I was too lazy to write everything by hand, so I just copied it, but I forgot to change the variables.